# Can I somehow access d_func() of QTableView from its subclass?

Tags: c++, qt, qtableview

I'm trying to fix strange QtableView behaviour: if one delete row but not commit data, it stays visible in grid. So, I need to retrieve data about deleted rows and know when we discard changes.
Info I need is stored in

```
d->cache[row].op
```

of qtableview. Can I somehow get it from there in my subclass?

If no, can I somehow achieve info about pending deletions? The only way I know is to store data when removeRows or revertRow is being executed, but it leads to unnnecessary data duplication and is just unelegant.

Comment: It looks for me that you're doing something wrong. QTableView itself shouldn't store any data, it's just display for data from model. Read about Model/View/Delegate in Qt docs http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/model-view-programming.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't. It's by design. Only thing I can is reimplement class from QSqlTableModel, which has open pimpl header.